# java graphical user interface app is crashing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, if-statement

after i Added the first two if loops the application started crashing. the application is supposed to view advisors with their advisees and register new advisees... since i made the programs of study as JRadioButtons which is connected to the JComboBox which includes the Majors according to the choice. Right after clicking Register New student button the application is crashing and im not able to figure out whats the problem. the program runs fine but crashes after register new student button. this is the main class. there are 4 more classes included after it. knowing that the problem is in the main class as far i know.

---

AguDbaseApp.java;

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
 import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
 import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
 import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
 import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;



 import javax.swing.JTextArea;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JComboBox;

 public class AguDbaseApp extends JFrame {
     private JLabel advisorLabel, adviseeLabel, profTextAreaLabel, 
     studentTextAreaLabel, createStudentLabel, studentFullNameLabel,           studentIDLabel, collegeLabel,
programTextFieldLabel,gpaLabel;
private JComboBox advisors, advisees, college, program;
private JRadioButton cecButton, cobButton, cob_Button, cec_Button, allAdviseesButton, cgpaLessThan2Button, abovespecificCGPAbutton;
private JTextField cgpaTextField, studentFullNameTextField, studentID_TextField, gpa_TextField;
private ButtonGroup cgpaGrp, profGroup, majorGroup;
private JTextArea profDetails, studentDetails;
private JButton registerNewStudentButton;
//Create an array of type AguProfessor and set it to hold up to 50 objects
 private AguProfessor aguAdvisors[] = new AguProfessor[50];

 private AguStudent aguStudents[] = new AguStudent[100];
 int size;

 private String cec[]= {"CIS", "CSE"};
 private String cob[]= {"BBA", "MBA"};


public AguDbaseApp (){
    super( "AGU Advisor List" );
    setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );


            aguStudents[0] = new AguStudent("Hammad Beloushi", "20142247", "USA", 25, "CEC", "CIS", 3.45);
            aguStudents[1] = new AguStudent("James Holding", "20142248", "British", 29, "CEC", "CSE", 3.87);
            aguStudents[2] = new AguStudent("Fin Aaz", "20142249", "Indonesia", 25, "CEC", "CCS", 2.56);
            aguStudents[3] = new AguStudent("Josan Cruz", "20142250", "India", 25, "CEC", "CSE", 1.79);
            aguStudents[4] = new AguStudent("Smith Jobs", "20142251", "UK", 25, "CEC", "CIS", 1.95);
            aguStudents[5] = new AguStudent("Steve Solls", "20142252", "Canada", 25, "CoB", "CCS", 3.95);
            aguStudents[6] = new AguStudent("Ali Minhas", "20142253", "Pakistan", 25, "CoB", "CSE", 3.78);
            aguStudents[7] = new AguStudent("Mehdi Hassan", "20142254", "Spain", 25, "CoB", "CIS", 2.56);
            aguStudents[8] = new AguStudent("Greme Smith", "20142255", "Germany", 25, "CoB", "CCS", 1.56);
            aguStudents[9] = new AguStudent("Andrew Fin", "20142256", "Russia", 25, "CoB", "CSE", 1.85);
            size=10;



    //Declare and initialize an object of the GridBagConstraints class
       GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();
       gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
       gBC.ipadx = 10;
       gBC.ipady = 10; 
       gBC.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10);

       aguAdvisors[0] = new AguProfessor("James Carmichael", "E500", "Barbados", "CEC", 45, "associate", 18000);
       aguAdvisors[1] = new AguProfessor("Syed Ahmed", "E501", "India", "CEC", 40, "assistant", 15000);
       aguAdvisors[2] = new AguProfessor("Mohammed Ramzy", "E502", "Egypt", "CoB", 38, "assistant", 15000);
       aguAdvisors[3] = new AguProfessor("Ibrahim Siddiq", "E503", "Sudan", "CoB", 38, "associate", 18000);

           aguStudents[0].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[0]);
           aguStudents[1].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[1]);
           aguStudents[2].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[0]);
           aguStudents[3].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[1]);
           aguStudents[4].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[0]);
           aguStudents[5].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[2]);
           aguStudents[6].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[3]);
           aguStudents[7].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[2]);
           aguStudents[8].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[3]);
           aguStudents[9].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[2]);


       gBC.gridx = 0;
       gBC.gridy = 0;
       advisorLabel= new JLabel("Select Advising Professor:");
       add(advisorLabel, gBC);

       gBC.gridx = 0;
       gBC.gridy = 1;
       advisors = new JComboBox(); 
       advisors.setMaximumRowCount(3);
       add(advisors, gBC);
       advisors.setEditable(false);


       gBC.gridx = 1;
       gBC.gridy = 1;
       advisees = new JComboBox(); 
       advisees.setMaximumRowCount(3);
       add(advisees, gBC);
       advisees.setEditable(false);

       gBC.gridx = 1;
       gBC.gridy = 0;
       adviseeLabel = new JLabel("Advisee List for selected advisor:");
       add(adviseeLabel, gBC);

       gBC.ipady = 1;
       gBC.gridx = 2;
       gBC.gridy = 1;      
       allAdviseesButton = new JRadioButton( "Show All Advisees", false ); 
       add(allAdviseesButton, gBC);


       gBC.gridx = 2;
       gBC.gridy = 2; 
       cgpaLessThan2Button = new JRadioButton( "Show Advisees on probation", false );
       add(cgpaLessThan2Button, gBC);

       gBC.gridx = 2;
       gBC.gridy = 3; 
       abovespecificCGPAbutton = new JRadioButton( "Show Advisees with CGPA above:", false );
       add(abovespecificCGPAbutton, gBC);

       gBC.gridx = 3;
       gBC.gridy = 3;
       cgpaTextField = new JTextField(5);
       add(cgpaTextField, gBC);

       cgpaGrp = new ButtonGroup(); 
       cgpaGrp.add( allAdviseesButton);     
       cgpaGrp.add( cgpaLessThan2Button );
       cgpaGrp.add( abovespecificCGPAbutton );

       gBC.gridx = 0;
       gBC.gridy = 2;
       cecButton = new JRadioButton( "CEC Profs", false );
       add(cecButton, gBC);

       gBC.gridx = 0;
       gBC.gridy = 3;
       cobButton = new JRadioButton( "CoB Profs", false );
       add(cobButton, gBC);

     //Implement event handling for all objects using the ItemListener
       RadioButtonHandler radButtonHandler = new RadioButtonHandler();
       cecButton.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);
       cobButton.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);
       advisors.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);
           allAdviseesButton.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);
           cgpaLessThan2Button.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);
           abovespecificCGPAbutton.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);
           advisees.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);




       profGroup = new ButtonGroup(); 
       profGroup.add( cecButton);     
       profGroup.add( cobButton );


       gBC.gridx = 0;
       gBC.gridy = 4;
       profTextAreaLabel = new JLabel("Advisor Info");
       add(profTextAreaLabel, gBC);

       gBC.gridx = 1;
       gBC.gridy = 4;
       studentTextAreaLabel = new JLabel("Student Record(s)");
       add(studentTextAreaLabel, gBC);


       gBC.gridx = 0;
       gBC.gridy = 5;
       //We want the JTextArea object to span across 3 grid columns
       //so we set the 'gBC.gridwidth' variable to a value of '3'
       gBC.gridheight = 4;
       gBC.gridwidth = 1;



    //initialize the studentDetails JTextArea object,
    //specifying the number of rows and columns
    profDetails = new JTextArea(5, 35);  
    profDetails.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    profDetails.setEditable(false);
    profDetails.setToolTipText("Selected professor's details will appear in this text box");
    JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(profDetails);        
    add(scrollingArea, gBC);

    gBC.gridx = 1;
    gBC.gridy = 5;


    gBC.gridwidth = 3;

    studentDetails = new JTextArea(5, 35);  
    studentDetails.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    studentDetails.setEditable(false);
    studentDetails.setToolTipText("Selected student's transcript will appear in this text box");
    JScrollPane scrollingArea2 = new JScrollPane(studentDetails);        
    add(scrollingArea2, gBC);


   gBC.gridheight = 1;
   gBC.gridwidth = 1; 

    gBC.gridx = 0;
    gBC.gridy = 11;
    createStudentLabel = new JLabel("REGISTER A NEW STUDENT AND ASSIGN TO AN ADVISOR:");
    add(createStudentLabel, gBC);

    gBC.gridx = 0;
    gBC.gridy = 12;
    studentFullNameLabel = new JLabel("Enter Student's name");
    add(studentFullNameLabel, gBC);

    gBC.gridx = 0;
    gBC.gridy = 13;
    studentFullNameTextField = new JTextField(20);
    add(studentFullNameTextField, gBC);

    gBC.gridx = 1;
    gBC.gridy = 12;
    studentIDLabel = new JLabel("Enter Student's ID");
    add(studentIDLabel, gBC);

    gBC.gridx = 1;
    gBC.gridy = 13;
    studentID_TextField = new JTextField(20);
    add(studentID_TextField, gBC);

    gBC.gridx = 2;
    gBC.gridy = 13;
    registerNewStudentButton = new JButton("Register New Student");
    add(registerNewStudentButton, gBC);

        registerNewStudentButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String name = studentFullNameTextField.getText();
                    String id = studentID_TextField.getText();
                    double gpa = -1;
                    try{
                        gpa = Double.parseDouble(gpa_TextField.getText());

                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        gpa = -1;
                        System.out.println("Double Parsing error!!!");
                    }

                    if(name.length()>3&&id.length()>0&&profGroup.getSelection()!=null)
                    {
                        String colg = college.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String prog = program.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        aguStudents[size] = new AguStudent(name, id, "Null", 0, colg, prog, gpa);
                        for(int i=0; i<aguAdvisors.length; i++)
                        {
                            if(aguAdvisors[i]!=null&&aguAdvisors[i].getName().equals(advisors.getSelectedItem().toString()))
                            {
                                aguStudents[size].setAdvisor(aguAdvisors[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        studentFullNameTextField.setText("");
                        studentID_TextField.setText("");
                        gpa_TextField.setText("");
                    }
                }
    });

    gBC.gridx = 0;
    gBC.gridy = 14;
    collegeLabel = new JLabel("College of affiliation:");
    add(collegeLabel, gBC);

       gBC.gridx = 0;
       gBC.gridy = 15;
       cec_Button = new JRadioButton( "CEC ", false );
       add(cec_Button, gBC);

       gBC.gridx = 0;
       gBC.gridy = 16;
       cob_Button = new JRadioButton( "COB ", false );
       add(cob_Button, gBC);

       majorGroup = new ButtonGroup(); 
       majorGroup.add(cec_Button);
       majorGroup.add(cob_Button);
       cec_Button.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);
       cob_Button.addItemListener(radButtonHandler);

    gBC.gridx = 1;
    gBC.gridy = 14;
    programTextFieldLabel = new JLabel("Program for this student: ");
    add(programTextFieldLabel, gBC); 

    gBC.gridx = 1;
    gBC.gridy = 15;
        program = new JComboBox();
        program.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        add(program, gBC);
        program.setEditable(false);



//      programTextField = new JTextField(10);
//      add(programTextField, gBC);

        gBC.gridx = 2;
        gBC.gridy = 15;
        gpaLabel = new JLabel("                                                               GPA");
        add(gpaLabel, gBC);

        gBC.gridx = 3;
        gBC.gridy = 15;
        gpa_TextField = new JTextField(3);
        add(gpa_TextField, gBC);



} // end of constructor

public void writeInfoToProfTextArea() {

    profDetails.setText("");
       for (int y=0; y < aguAdvisors.length; y++){
           if(aguAdvisors[y]!=null && advisors.getItemCount()>0){
               if (aguAdvisors[y].toString().trim().equals(advisors.getSelectedItem().toString().trim() )) {
                   profDetails.append("Professor's full name: " + aguAdvisors[y].getName());
                   profDetails.append("\nProfessor's e-mail:" + aguAdvisors[y].getEmail());
                   profDetails.append("\nProfessor's AGU College: " + aguAdvisors[y].getCollege());
                   profDetails.append("\nProfessor's AGU ID: " + aguAdvisors[y].getID());

               }                       
           }

       }

}

    public void writeInfoToStdTextArea(){

        studentDetails.setText("");
        for(int i=0; i<aguStudents.length; i++)
        {
            if(aguStudents[i]!=null&&advisees.getItemCount()>0)
            {
                if(aguStudents[i].getID().equals(advisees.getSelectedItem().toString()))
                {
                    studentDetails.append("Name: "+aguStudents[i].getName());
                    studentDetails.append("\tID: "+ aguStudents[i].getID());
                    studentDetails.append("\nCollege: "+ aguStudents[i].getCollege());
                    studentDetails.append("\t\tProgram of Study: "+ aguStudents[i].getProgram());
                    studentDetails.append("\nAdvisor: "+ aguStudents[i].getAdvisor().getName());
                    studentDetails.append("\tCGPA: "+aguStudents[i].getCGPA());
                }
            }
        }
    }


private class RadioButtonHandler implements ItemListener {
      public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent radioButtonEvent ) {


           if (radioButtonEvent.getSource()==cec_Button) {
                //clear all items from the JComboBox object
                   program.removeAllItems();

                int f;
                for (f=0; f< cec.length; f++){
                 if (cec[f]!=null) {
                  if (cec[f].trim() != null) {
                      program.addItem(cec[f]);

                  }
                 }
                }
           }
           else if (radioButtonEvent.getSource()==cob_Button) {
                //clear all items from the JComboBox object
                   program.removeAllItems();

                int f;
                for (f=0; f< cob.length; f++){
                 if (cob[f]!=null) {
                  if (cob[f].trim() != null) {
                      program.addItem(cob[f]);
                  }
                 }
                }
           }
                else if (radioButtonEvent.getSource()==cecButton) {
        //clear all items from the JComboBox object
           advisors.removeAllItems();

        //clear all text from the JTextArea object
        profDetails.setText("");
        int i;
        for (i=0; i< aguAdvisors.length; i++){
         if (aguAdvisors[i]!=null) {
          if (aguAdvisors[i].getCollege().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("CEC")) {
              advisors.addItem(aguAdvisors[i]);
          }
         }
        }
        writeInfoToProfTextArea();

       } else if (radioButtonEvent.getSource()==cobButton) {
        //clear all items from the JComboBox object
           advisors.removeAllItems();

        //clear all text from the JTextArea object
        profDetails.setText("");


        for (int j=0; j< aguAdvisors.length; j++) {
         if (aguAdvisors[j]!=null) {
          if (aguAdvisors[j].getCollege().equalsIgnoreCase("CoB")) {
              advisors.addItem(aguAdvisors[j]);
          }
         }
        } 
        writeInfoToProfTextArea();

       } else if (radioButtonEvent.getSource()==advisors){
           writeInfoToProfTextArea();

       }
               if((radioButtonEvent.getSource() == allAdviseesButton)&& (profGroup.getSelection()!=null))
               {
                   advisees.removeAllItems();
                   studentDetails.setText("");
                   for(int i=0; i<aguStudents.length; i++)
                   {
                       if(aguStudents[i]!=null)
                       {
                           if(aguStudents[i].getAdvisor().getName().equals(advisors.getSelectedItem().toString()))
                           {
                               advisees.addItem(aguStudents[i].getID());
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   writeInfoToStdTextArea();
               }
               else if((radioButtonEvent.getSource()==  cgpaLessThan2Button)&&(profGroup.getSelection()!=null))
               {
                   advisees.removeAllItems();
                   studentDetails.setText("");
                   for(int i=0; i<aguStudents.length; i++)
                   {
                       if(aguStudents[i]!=null)
                       {
                           if((aguStudents[i].getAdvisor().getName().equals(advisors.getSelectedItem().toString()))&&(aguStudents[i].getCGPA()<2.00))
                           {
                               advisees.addItem(aguStudents[i].getID());
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   writeInfoToStdTextArea();
               }
               else if((radioButtonEvent.getSource()==  abovespecificCGPAbutton)&&(profGroup.getSelection()!=null)&&(cgpaTextField.getText().length()>0))
               {
                   advisees.removeAllItems();
                   studentDetails.setText("");
                   double cgpa = Double.parseDouble(cgpaTextField.getText());
                   for(int i=0; i<aguStudents.length; i++)
                   {
                       if(aguStudents[i]!=null)
                       {
                           if((aguStudents[i].getAdvisor().getName().equals(advisors.getSelectedItem().toString()))&&(aguStudents[i].getCGPA()> cgpa))
                           {
                               advisees.addItem(aguStudents[i].getID());
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   writeInfoToStdTextArea();
               }
               else if(radioButtonEvent.getSource()==advisees)
               {
                   writeInfoToStdTextArea();
               }

              }
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AguDbaseApp aguDbase = new AguDbaseApp();

    aguDbase.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );


    // set frame size by specifying x-coordinate and y-coordinate
    aguDbase.setSize( 1000, 600 ); //the setSize() method takes the x coordinate, then y
    aguDbase.setVisible( true ); // display frame
 }

}
```

---

AguPerson.java;

```
 public abstract class AguPerson {
 protected String nationality;
 protected String name;
 protected String id;
 protected String eMail;
 protected String college;
 protected int age;



  public AguPerson(String ismay, String iD, String nat, String coll, int ag) {

  name = ismay;
  id = iD;
  nationality=nat;
  age = ag;  
  eMail = null;
  college = coll;
  }

public AguPerson(String ismay, String iD, String nat, String coll, String email, int ag) {    
  name = ismay;
  id = iD;
  nationality=nat;
  age = ag;
  eMail = email;
  college = coll;
  }

    public void setCollege (String newCollege){
    college = newCollege;
}

public String getCollege (){
    return college;
}

  public String getName() {   
  return name;
  }

  public void setName (String newName){
  name =newName;
  }

  public String getID() {
  return id;
  }
  public String getEmail() { return eMail; };
  public abstract void setEmail();


}
```

---

AguProfessor.java,

```
public class AguProfessor extends AguPerson {
private String rank; // can be "assistant", "associate" or "full"
private double monthlySalary;
//Implement a class field of type AguProfessor (which will represent the student's advisor).
//and don't forget to implement the usual 'get' and 'set' methods

public AguProfessor (String fullName, String iD, String nat, String coll, int ag, String rnk, double sal) {
    super(fullName, iD, nat, coll, ag);
     rank = rnk;  monthlySalary = sal;
             setEmail();
}

    @Override
public void setEmail() {
    eMail = name.replaceAll(" ", "") + "@agu.ac.ae";
}

public void setSalary(){
    if(rank.equalsIgnoreCase("assistant")){
        monthlySalary=15000;
    } else if (rank.equalsIgnoreCase("associate")){
        monthlySalary=18000;
    } else if (rank.equalsIgnoreCase("full")){
        monthlySalary=21000;
    }
}

public String toString(){
    return name;
}

}
```

---

AguStudent.java;

```
public class AguStudent<string> extends AguPerson implements Comparable<AguStudent> {

private String program; 
private Transcript transcr;
private AguProfessor advisor;
private double cgpa, gpa;

public AguStudent (String fullName, String iD, String nat, int ag, String coll, String prog, Double gpa) {
    super(fullName, iD, nat, coll, ag);

    program = prog; cgpa = gpa;     
}

public void setEmail() {
    eMail = id+"agu.ac.ae";
}   

public void setProgram (String newProgram){
    program = newProgram;
}

public String getProgram (){
    return program;
}   

public void setNationality (String newNationality){
    nationality = newNationality;
}

public String getNationality (){
    return nationality;
}   

public void setgpa (Double newgpa){
    gpa = newgpa;
}

public Double getgpa (){
    return gpa;
}   

public void setCGPA (double newCGPA){
    cgpa = newCGPA;
}

public double getCGPA (){
    return cgpa;
}

public int compareTo(AguStudent otherStudent) {
    if(this.getCGPA() < otherStudent.getCGPA()) {
        return -1;
    } else if(this.getCGPA() == otherStudent.getCGPA()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

public String toString(){
    return name;
}

    public void setAdvisor(AguProfessor advisor){
        this.advisor = advisor;
    }

    public AguProfessor getAdvisor(){
        return advisor;
    }

 }
```

---

Transcript.java;

```
public class Transcript {

private String[][] courseCodesAndGrades = new String[50][2];
private double[] creditHours = new double[50];
private String studentID, studentName;
private double cGPA=0;



public Transcript(String name, String id, String[][] codesAndGrades, double[] credits) {
    studentName= name;
    studentID = id;
    addCourseCodesAndGrades(codesAndGrades);
    addCredits(credits);
}


public Transcript(String name, String id) {
    studentName= name;
    studentID = id;
}


public String getStudentID(){   return studentID;   }

public void setStudentID(String newID){  studentID = newID; } 

public String getStudentName(){ return studentName;  } 





//TASK 1: Insert values for the "B+", "C+",  "D+", "F" and "WF" grades. NOTE that 
//a "WF" grade does not affect the GPA score calculations
//NOTE: This is a static or class method. 

public static double convertGradeToPoints(String  someGrade, double creditHours) {
    double points = 0;
    if (someGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
        points = 4;
    } else if (someGrade.equals("B+")) {
        points = 3.5;
    } else if (someGrade.equals("B")) {
        points = 3;
    } else if (someGrade.equals("C+")) { //What is the difference between "equals()" and "equalsIgnoreCase()"?
        points = 2.5;
    }else if (someGrade.equals("C")) {
            points = 2;

    }else if (someGrade.equals("B+")) {
            points = 1.5;

    } else if (someGrade.equals("D")) {
        points = 1;
    }
    return points*creditHours;
}


public static double convertGradesToGPA(String[] grades, double[] credHours) {  

    double totalGradePoints =0, totalCreditHours=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
        if(grades[i]!=null){
            totalGradePoints += convertGradeToPoints(grades[i], credHours[i]);
            totalCreditHours += credHours[i];
        }
    }
    return totalGradePoints/totalCreditHours; 
}



public void addCourseCodesAndGrades(String[][] aFewCoursesAndGrades){
    //TASK 2: Modify this implementation so that duplicate courses cannot
    //be added, e.g. the course code "CSE 233" should only appear ONCE 

    int counter = 0;

    while(courseCodesAndGrades[counter][0]!=null){
        counter++;
    }

    for(int y = 0; y < aFewCoursesAndGrades.length; y++){
        if(courseCodesAndGrades[counter][0]!=null) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            courseCodesAndGrades[counter][0]= aFewCoursesAndGrades[y][0];
            courseCodesAndGrades[counter][1]= aFewCoursesAndGrades[y][1];
            counter++;
        }
    }
} // end of addCourseCodesAndGrades()method


public void addCredits(double[] aFewCredits){


    int counter = 0;

    while(creditHours[counter]!=0){
        counter++;
    } 

    for (int x = 0; x < aFewCredits.length; x++){
        if(creditHours[counter]==0 ){
            creditHours[counter] = aFewCredits[x];
            counter++;
        } else { 
            counter++;
        }
    } 
}//end of addCredits method 

public String getAllCoursesAndGrades() {
    String allCoursesAndGrades = "";
    for(int y = 0; y < courseCodesAndGrades.length; y++){
        if(courseCodesAndGrades[y][0]!=null){

            allCoursesAndGrades += courseCodesAndGrades[y][0] + ", " + courseCodesAndGrades[y][1] + "; ";
        } 
    }
        return allCoursesAndGrades;
} //end of getAllCoursesAndGrades() method

private void calculateGPA() {
    String[] allGrades = new String[courseCodesAndGrades.length];
    double[] credHrs = new double[creditHours.length]; 

    for(int z = 0; z < courseCodesAndGrades.length; z++){
        if(courseCodesAndGrades[z][1]!=null){
            allGrades[z]= courseCodesAndGrades[z][1];
            credHrs[z] =creditHours[z];
        } // end of if statement
    } // end of for loop 

    cGPA = convertGradesToGPA(allGrades, credHrs);
}

public double getCGPA(){ 
    calculateGPA();
    return cGPA; 
} // of getCGPA() method
}// end of Transcript class
```

Comment: You need to include what error you are getting and where.

Comment: i mentioned it ... if i run the application it runs fine but it crashes right after clicking the register new student button and it only show the error in the compiler, eclipse. in the application you wont get any sign of a crash but in eclipse you'll see that it crashed

Comment: `String colg = college.getSelectedItem().toString();` seems to be causing a `NullPointerException`, I strongly recommend that you fire up your debugger and figure out why, as I suspect that it's not the only one

Comment: `college` is never initialised

Comment: what can i do in this case??? because i dont have any use for college... but if i delete i cant because its connected to the AguPerson class...

Comment: There is a `JComboBox college` in your `AguDbaseApp.java` so I am guessing, before you click the button to create a new student, you have to select an item from the `JComboBox`? Do you select a college in the `JComboBox` or do you leave it empty? Can you try to select an item and not select an item, what happens in both cases?